# C# connecting to Oracle (configure tnsnames.ora)

Tags: c#, oracle, oracle11g

So a newbie to database here. Found many questions related to my problem but couldn't solve it.

I installed Oracle 11g and with it comes the pre configured database named "orcl" that has all the data regarding the employees. Now im trying to connect to this database through C# but i found that there are 2 ways of writing the `Connection String`

If the alias isn't set up in `tnsnames.ora` file then it's done by

```
con_string = "Data Source=(DESCRIPTION=(ADDRESS_LIST=(ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=TCP)(HOST=localhost)(PORT=1521)))(CONNECT_DATA=(SERVER=DEDICATED)(SERVICE_NAME=service_name)));User Id=myid;Password=mypass"
```

Now what i don't understand is, what should i write in place of "localhost". As far as i know `Port` is 1521 by default. Searching over the net tells me i should write my IP address here? Sorry but i am a noob when it comes to networking so what IP address? my LAN ip address? The one i can get through ipconfig or the WAN IP address?

Secondly why is there a need for IP address? Isn't the database on my PC so there shouldn't be any need for internet connection?

I also need to know what exactly should i write in place of `service name`

Currently i've tried putting my LAN and WAN IP address in place of local host. and it gives me the error "Connection request timed out". Do note im using the `ManagedDataAccess` driver not the unmanaged one. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

HOST - there you must type your that server ip address which you installed oracle database. if you installed oracle db to local, then you can set HOST parameter to localhost, if you installed on any virtual machine, then you must set that virtual machine ip address.